# Need To Make Things Happen In Background Based On Day Of Week And Time

Tags: java, android, datetime, background

I have no idea on where to start but I have made the GUI for my app and need to make things happen based upon the variables I have stored in a SharedPreferences that are based on the Day of the week and time, I would just like to know some of the best ways I can make things happen in the background based on date and time, thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at AlarmManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To run things in background, you need a `Service`

   ```
   public class MyService extends Service {

       @Override
       public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags,
                         final int startId) {
           // parse the intent and run your things
           return START_NOT_STICKY;
       }
   }
   ```
2. To to things automatically on specific time, you need `AlarmManager`

   ```
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context
           .ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, BlockchainService.class);
   // customize your intent
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
           alarmIntent, 0);
   alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, your_specific_time, pendingIntent);
   ```
3. Start service and prevent sleep

   Related answer [AlarmManager not working in sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206021/alarmmanager-not-working-in-sleep-mode)

Comment: So would the AlarmManager start the service even when the app that contains the alam manger is not open?

Comment: One more Question, Would My alarm manager start the service even when the device is locked?

Comment: @endlesschaos found you a related answer
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206021/alarmmanager-not-working-in-sleep-mode